# HashMap. Вывод значения по ключу

Tags: java, java-hashmap

В HashMap хрянятся ключ-значение, пользователь вводит ключ, программа выводит значение. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Вот ровно то, что просится в вашем вопросе

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ключ", "значение");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(map.get(scanner.nextLine()));
```